# Minimal polynomial substitution

Tags: minimal-polynomials, cayley-hamilton

This is probably a very easy question, I'm just not strong at the concept.

Let $ A $ be an $ n \times n $ matrix with coefficient in a field $ F $. Then $ A $ determines a linear map $ T: F^n \to F^n $ and gives $ F^n $ a $ F[x] $-module. The characteristic polynomial of $ A $ is $ \text{det}(xI - A) $, while the minimal polynomial is defined to be the monic polynomial generating $ \text{Ann}(F^n) $ as the above $ F[x] $-module.

When finding the invariant factors, the method I see is to calculate the minimal polynomial by using the determinant formula. For example, say it is $ (x-2)^2(x-3) $. Now the minimal polynomial is either $ (x-2)(x-3) $ or $ (x-2)^2(x-3) $. But in the next step, the book substitutes in $ (A- 2I)(A-3I) $ and check if it's zero. Why is this possible? This looks like the Cayley-Hamilton theorem, but isn't that only for characteristic polynomials?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the most convenient way. The minimal polynomial is the monic polynomial of minimum degree (on the given field) which vanishes at the endomorphism ($A$ in your example). Certainly the polynomial you found (the characterisic one) vanishes at $A$ but you don't know if it is also the minimal polynomial, so you must check if its proper divisors (with all irreducible factors) vanish at the matrix.

Comment: If the minimal polynomial is defined to be that way, then I agree. I guess my problem is that I don't see how from the definition of being the generator of the annihilator, one gets the equivalent definition?

Comment: Being the minimal polynomial the generator of the (principal bilateral) ideal $Ann(F^n)$ it divides each polynomial which evaluated on $A$ acts trivially on the space, id est it divides each polynomials wich vanishes at $A$ (it is the minimum w.r.t. divisibility, a stronger property of degree comparison)

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same question a few months ago, but now I've resolved it and I think and I can be very helpful in resolving this for you too as I'll only use simple definitions.

An **annihilator polynomial** for any matrix $A$ is a polynomial function $f$ such that $f(A)=0$. By the *Caley-Hamilton theorem*, the characteristic polynomial of $A$ is an annihilator of $A$.

The **minimal polynomial** of any matrix $A$ is defined to be **a monic polynomial of least degree which annihilates $A$**.

The *Caley-Hamilton theorem* doesn't imply that the characteristic polynomial is an annihilator polynomial of least degree, so to find the minimal polynomial, we check for its factors. Since $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ iff it's a root of the minimal polynomial, to check for the minimal polynomial, we only check for those factors of characteristic polynomial which contains all the distinct eigenvalues as its roots.

Thank you for reading my answer.

Comment: @YuiTo Cheng, that edit was unnecessary. My edits were much more relevant in other posts but you rejected them. Stop abusing your privileges.